# Scala. How get last word in String

Tags: scala

Given a String, how to get the last word in Scala, assuming words divided by space?

Example:

```
val s = "Hello world1, world2, world"
```

Expected output: `"world"`

Comment: There are many ways.. `s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);` ?

Comment: s.split("\\s+").toList.filter(_.length > 0).last

Comment: @litehause You are probably being voted down because your question does not show your attempt and merely asks for an answer. Can you show us some of your attempts and we can provide you clues as to why those failed as well as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go by a `string.split(" ").lastOption`. But keep in mind that other blank chars may be used instead of space

Answer (score 2):

```
   def lastW(s: String) = {
      @tailrec
      def lw(s: Array[Char], i: Int = s.length-1, w: String=""): String = s(i) match {
        case(' ') => w
        case c if i == 0 => c+w
        case c => lw(s, i-1, c+w)
      }
      lw(s.toCharArray)
    }
```

Nah, just kidding. Just do this:

```
 string.split("").reverse.takeWhile(_ != " ").reverse.mkString("")
```

Or this:

```
  string.replaceAll("^.* ", "")
```

Or this:

```
 "\\S+$".r.findFirstIn(string).get
```

Or maybe:

```
 string.split(" ").last
```

Or

```
 string.split(" ").reverse.head
```

Etc.

Comment: Note that the last 3 options use partial functions: `get`, `last` and `head`.

Comment: They are not partial functions.

Comment: `head is what is known as a partial function: there are certain inputs for which head will crash. Functions which have certain inputs that will make them recurse infinitely are also called partial. Functions which are well-defined on all possible inputs are known as total functions.` -[Prof. Brent Yorgey](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/03-rec-poly.html)

Comment: I don't know who this professor is, but he is wrong. :)
A partial function in scala is a very specific thing, and these are not it. Check this out: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction

Comment: By that definition, `.r` is a "partial function" too, as well as `.split`, and `.replaceAll` (all will crash if pattern is invalid), and so are `.mkString` (crashes if `.toString` throws on one of the elements), `s(i)` (crashes if index is out of range), `lastW` (crashes if `s` is null among other cases), etc.

Comment: Yes - I spoke too soon **and incorrectly**. `A partial function of type PartialFunction[A, B] is a unary function where the domain does not necessarily include all values of type A` -[docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction)